# CSS Transition IE Problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to build a simple css card flip style page and it works on all browsers except IE 11 and I'm not sure why. I assume it has something to do with the following code:

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);

    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);

}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle... test in Chrome to see it working as intended and then check in IE 11 to see it breaking.

https://jsfiddle.net/xebcx8gt/2/

Answer (score 0):

You must specify which CSS property you want to add a transition to. I'd guess that Chrome is forgiving and assumes you meant `all` when nothing is specified.

Change your `transition: 0.6s;` to `transition: transform 0.6s;`.

For more information on the `transition` property and its syntax, check out [MDN's page on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Comment: any other ideas? It seems nobody has an answer for this issue.